# Hacer que un elemento aparezca solo una vez

Tags: javascript, html, html5

El problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un `div` en mi `Index` que quiero que se muestre solo cuando se carga la página por primera vez, dicho `Div` tiene un botón de Entrar, una vez que entra a la página, este `div` se oculta y aparece el resto del contenido de mi `Index`. El problema es que si voy a otra sección de la página y quiero regresar al inicio, el `Div` que estaba oculto vuelve a aparecer y debo nuevamente Entrar a la página.

Estoy utilizando el evento `onclick` en dicho `div`.

```
<section>
<div id="enter">
<img class="onoOne" src="img/ono_white.svg" alt="">
<input type="button" value="Enter" id="btnEnter" onclick="hide()" >
</div>
</section>

<script>
const btnEnter = document.querySelector("#btnEnter");

function hide(){
btnEnter.style.display = "none";
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Si no lo necesitas en esa otra página, con no poner el div en el html, debería bastarte. O es una página dinámica?

Comment: Supongo que estás trabajando con páginas puras de HTML. En ese caso te recomiendo almacenar en el navegador un valor, por ejemplo, 'divMostrado=true'. Y cada vez que cambies de página lees este valor.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es almacenar una variable en el `localStorage` del navegador, luego verificar si existe esa variable.

Prueba el siguiente código:

```js
const btnEnter = document.querySelector("#btnEnter");

if(localStorage.getItem("btn")){
    btnEnter.style.display = "none";
}else{
    function hide(){
        localStorage.setItem("btn", true);
        btnEnter.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div id="enter" style="padding-top: 200px">
        <img class="onoOne" src="img/ono_white.svg" alt="">
        <input type="button" value="Enter" id="btnEnter" onclick="hide()" >
    </div>
</section>
```

> Nota: Stackoverflow no me permite almacenar datos en localStorage.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado perfectamente.

Comment: Que bueno, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

La solución más fácil a tu problema es utilizar [sessionStorage](https://ed.team/blog/que-es-y-como-utilizar-localstorage-y-sessionstorage). En el puedes guardar una variable por ejemplo para saber si esta persona se le ha mostrado ya este boton.

En la función `hide()` añade una línea tal que `sessionStorage.visitado = "true"` (tanto en session como en local, solo se guardan Strings). Y luego en el index haz una comprobación de si esta variable existe o no `if (sessionStorage.visitado === "true")`y pinta el div en consecuencia.

También podrías hacerlo con [cookies](https://cybmeta.com/cookies-en-javascript) por si quieres echarle un vistazo.

Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha funcionado usar el sessionStorage.